# is this sentence is grammatically right?- a lot of bucks is shelled out.

Tags: grammar

A lot of bucks is shelled out. ... Is this sentence is grammatically right? I have a doubt in 'is' either here singular 'is' come or pural 'are' aftr 'bucks'..

Comment: Is there one buck or more than one buck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is talking of a lot of bucks (plural), not a buck (singular).  So he must use the plural verb are instead of is. The phrase "a lot of" is used with a plural noun, if the noun is countable. However, if you use the phrase with an uncountable noun, you use the verb in the singular such as there is a lot of sugar.